# UIPageViewController scroll automatically

Tags: xcode, ios6, pagecontrol

I'm using an UIPageViewController with a PageControl to display 3 images in my PageViewController. All works perfect. But is it possible that the Pages are swiping (scrolling) to the next page after a specific time automatically?

Comment: use NSTimer for achieve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSTimer to scroll after particular time.I hope following code will help you

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(move_pagination) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

after that define "move_pagination" method like

```
- (void)scrollingTimer {

UIScrollView *scrMain = (UIScrollView*) [self.view viewWithTag:1];

UIPageControl *pgCtr = (UIPageControl*) [self.view viewWithTag:12];

CGFloat contentOffset = scrMain.contentOffset.x;
// calculate next page to display
int nextPage = (int)(contentOffset/scrMain.frame.size.width) + 1 ;
// if page is not 10, display it
if( nextPage!=10 )  {
    [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(nextPage*scrMain.frame.size.width, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    pgCtr.currentPage=nextPage;
// else start sliding form 1 :)
} else {
    [scrMain scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, scrMain.frame.size.width, scrMain.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    pgCtr.currentPage=0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

this is possible with this below method

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers direction:(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection)direction animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

For Ex:

```
[pageVCObj setViewControllers:arrayOfViewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This moves to the next page but not in an animated manner. Is there some method to scroll automatically with animation?

Comment: Incorrect answer, guy asked about automatically. this code will not work automatic.